# Use of @media for responsive eBay templates

Tags: css, templates, responsive

I wanted to use the CSS3 `@media` rule to make an ebay ad template responsive, but since ebay puts my HTML into an iframe, and moreover inside a div of an HTML page beginning with script, the `@media` rule gets ignored. My template works responsively if tested outside of the ebay iframe, but if I put the same code in ebay, it looks like @media gets completely ignored.

It really looks like for the `@media` rule to be honored, it needs to be defined at the whole canvas level, that is in the overall containing document, but ebay won't allow me to modify that. Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries - it will work on mobile etc, though on desktop the iframe size is determined on load by ebay, so wont resize well.  you will just have the iframe stay too big and creating a scroll bar at times, though the contents can repsond still.  Its awkward unfortunately.